# Unexpected result using nested if statements

Tags: c++

Here is what I have coded so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
      int num;
      cout << "Enter a month(as a number): ";
      cin >> num;
      if (num < 3 || num > 11)
      {
        cout << "Happy Winter\n";
      }
      else if (num > 7 || num < 9)
      {
        cout << "Happy Summer\n";
      }
      else if (num > 3 || num < 7)
      {
        cout << "Happy Spring\n";
      }
      else
      {
        cout << "Happy Fall\n";
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

My program is not printing things how it is supposed to. My progrma is supposed to print:
"Happy Winter" if it is strictly before 3 or strictly larger than 11,
"Happy Spring" if it is 3 or greater, but strictly before 7, and
"Happy Summer" if it is 7 or greater, but strictly before 9, and
"Happy Fall" otherwise.

but for some reason it only prints "Happy Summer" no matter what number i input. the only line that works is the first if statement i coded. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong but i think it has to do with my my operations in the else if statements.

Comment: For a small set of options, consider using `switch`.

Comment: opposit of `num > 7` must be `num <= 7`. your current code does not work well when num is exactly 7.

Comment: If you input `1`, you will get `"Happy Winter"`.

Comment: @Nick " it only prints "Happy Summer" no matter what number i input"

Comment: @NeilButterworth Ah, I missed that part >.< as they said *"the only line that works is the first if statement"*, so I assumed they meant besides *"Happy Winter"*

Answer (score 4):

Take a look again at this, it's true if the number is less than 9 or greater than 7:

```
(num > 7 || num < 9)
```

That's all numbers.

You should be using and(`&&`) instead, the same is the case for your `(num > 3 || num < 7)`.

Also note that your `if` statements miss out 3, so it's being classed as Fall. This is easy to miss because you're only strictly using only less than and greater than, rather than less/greater than or equal to.

Perhaps look at this:

```
if (num >= 3 && num <= 5) {
    cout << "Happy Spring\n";
} else if (num >= 6 && num <= 8) {
    cout << "Happy Summer\n";
} else if (num >= 9 && num <= 11) {
    cout << "Happy Fall\n";
} else {
    cout << "Happy Winter\n";
}
```

This specifically looks at months 3-5, then 6-8 then 9-11 and then the rest.

You should also consider reading [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)